# Good book for algebra after Herstein?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

What is a good book to read after herstein's topics in algebra?

I've read in reviews somewhere that it's a bit shallow...

The main interests are algebraic and differential geometry. I prefer books with challenging excersices.

Something that crossed my mind: prehaps
 it's preferable that I should learn different topics from different books?

Comment: I would concur that Herstein is a bit topical in its approach.

Comment: How is differential geometry and abstract algebra related? I really like differential geometry but I dislike group theory.

Comment: Lie groups and lie algebra's are kind of a connection I'm told. maybe even http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringed_space

Answer (score 2):

I think Atiyah-Macdonald's [Commutative Algebra](http://lisabeckphotography.com/Math/Textbooks/Algebra/Atiyah%20and%20Macdonald%20-%20Introduction%20to%20Commutative%20Algebra%20text.pdf) could be a good choice if you want learn something about Ring Theory. 
Another (very) advanced book could be S.Lang - Algebra, but it is a Leviathan for an undergraduate math student.

Comment: I read that Lang's has a lot of mistakes. Is there a book as comprehensive as Lang's yet friendlier in the sense that it is clear? And I like challenging excersices that's why I picked herstein.

Comment: @user106581 May be the 2 volume book by Nathan Jacobson could be an alternate to Lang ? I am not sure.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that book. But, if you're interested, I've learned a lot by M.Reid - Undergraduate Commutative Algebra.

Answer (score 2):

One of my favourite texts for mid-level algebra is Dummit and Foote's $\textit{Abstract Algebra}$. Another good text is Eisenbud's $\textit{Commutative Algebra (With a View Towards Algebraic Geometry)}$. This book is more of a graduate level text book.

Comment: When I say midlevel, I am speaking of intro to Galois Theory, module theory, representation theory.....Your basic advanced undergrad, starting grad student text.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend 'Algebra' by T Hungerford. After learning some commutative algebra, you may like to pursue Homological Algebra from say Weibel or Rotman (since you are interested in learning Algebraic geometry). And for learning more about commutative algebra you may like to see the books by Matsumura or Kaplansky.

There is also a comprehensive 2 volume book on Algebra by Nathan Jacobson.

Comment: I must add that I am not sure which of these should have tough exercises, though the books I mention are quite well known.